# Is it possible to direclty read a variable from a service worker (ServiceWorkerGlobalScope)?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is it possible to get the `counter` variable (ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) from the main thread **without** using the postMessage method?

service-worker.js:

```
    let counter = 42;

    self.addEventListener("message", function (event: any) {
        let client = event.source;
        client.postMessage(counter);
    }
```

Comment: is this an attempt to get an answer to your other question? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233906/are-web-worker-service-worker-secure-environments-to-store-a-password-credit

Comment: @schroeder yes, it's a more specific part of the other question

Comment: This is a little too specific ... And it is missing all the relevant context. We can't determine what's possible without understanding the whole code, and we really don't perform code reviews/analysis.

Comment: @schroeder it's supposed to be a very general question. Is data like the counter variable within the context of a service worker easily exposed for example in case the somebody has control over the main javscript thread? E.g., meaning if the counter is exposed to attacks similar to attacks which scrape the local storage, session storage or cookies.

Comment: without digging through code, all we can say is "no, it's not supposed to be possible.